# How to monitor delays(background process) in Java Swing Application using jprogressbar

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar

How to monitor delays(background process) in Java Swing Application using jprogressbar.

I want to monitor any delays or process in my Java Swing Application.

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking.  Can you provide an example or use-case which describes the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: ok I have a problem in my Java Swing Application everytime I try to run my app it seems like my app is too long to response I mean delays. That's why I like to make a modal dialog using jprogressbar to indicate the response of the java application.

Comment: This is the scenario the JFRAME load first and then 10 sec delays to load the components like menus, desktoppanes and the jpanels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try having a look at [`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html), see [How to use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for more details.

If this doesn't meet your needs or your problem is more complicated or you want more control, then you should consider using a `SwingWorker`, which has progress support via it's `PropertyChangeListener` support

> This is the scenario the JFRAME load first and then 10 sec delays to load the components like menus, desktoppanes and the jpanels

If the deal is in loading the UI components, then you don't have many options, as this will need to be done within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, which would block any other UI content you wanted to display

It's possible that something like the [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) would help as it can run in a different thread.  See [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for more details

Comment: I already use swingworker. I'm having hard time on how do I make this when I try to get the response of the application.

Comment: Well, everything so far is speculation, as I don't know what part of your app you are trying to optimise.  If the "lag" is in the loading of the components themselves, then `SwingWorker` won't help you, if the "lag" is in the loading of the data for the components then it will

Comment: I come up with idea to use modal dialog instead of using splash screens in  delays. Thank you for sharing your ideas and I really appreciate it.